# How to apply a webkit linear gradient to all the other prefixes?

Tags: css

I have created the following linear gradient for webkit background-image: `-webkit-repating-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 62px, black 62px, black 63px);` but Im unsure how to create the same style in opera, mozilla etc. Can some advise how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 62px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 63px); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(62px,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(63px,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 62px,rgba(0,0,0,1) 63px); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 62px,rgba(0,0,0,1) 63px); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 62px,rgba(0,0,0,1) 63px); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 62px,rgba(0,0,0,1) 63px); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now take this**

```
.mydiv   {
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 62px, black 62px, black 63px);  
        -moz-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 62px, black 62px, black 63px); // for firefox 
        -o-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 62px, black 62px, black 63px); // for opera
    }
```